# Is it possible to use WP_USER_QUERY to search by username using a wildcard?

Tags: buddypress, wp-user-query

As above guys, I'm trying to build an AJAX search that works within BuddyPress WITHOUT modifying core code, but that allows me to use a wildcard when I'm searching by username.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following class in the add user autocomplete plugin . It extends the normal searcha and allows '*';

Example: $wp_user_search = new A2B_User_Query( array( 'search' => $s . '*' ) ) ;

class A2B_User_Query extends WP_User_Query {
    /**
     * @see WP_User_Query::get_search_sql()
     */
    function get_search_sql( $string, $cols, $wild = false ) {
        $string = esc_sql( $string );

```
    // Always search all columns
    $cols = array(
        'user_email',
        'user_login',
        'user_nicename',
        'user_url',
        'display_name'
    );

    // Always do 'both' for trailing_wild
    $wild = 'both';

    $searches = array();
    $leading_wild = ( 'leading' == $wild || 'both' == $wild ) ? '%' : '';
    $trailing_wild = ( 'trailing' == $wild || 'both' == $wild ) ? '%' : '';
    foreach ( $cols as $col ) {
        if ( 'ID' == $col )
            $searches[] = "$col = '$string'";
        else
            $searches[] = "$col LIKE '$leading_wild" . like_escape($string) . "$trailing_wild'";
    }

    return ' AND (' . implode(' OR ', $searches) . ')';
}
```

}

Comment: +1. I wrote that plugin. It's intended for use in the Dashboard, but it could easily be adapted for frontend use.